# "FAILED pluginJSON" Error while Calling EmailComposerwithattachments PlugIn in Phonegap-2.3.0

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios6, phonegap-plugins

Hi I am using EmailcomposerWithAttachments Plugin from phonegap plugins. I am using Phonegap-2.3.0 and ios6 Simulator and latest Xcode.

I have placed the .m, .h files in Plugins folder of project and Js file in WWW folder and calling the plugin using

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer("Look at this photo","Take a look at <b>this<b/>:",["the.das@gmail.com", "dasthe@gmail.com"],[],[],true,[]);
```

js code as given in readme.md file. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposerWithAttachments

when i run it i am getting below error in Log.

```
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","EmailComposer","showEmailComposer",[{"subject":"Look at this photo","bIsHTML":true,"ccRecipients":[],"attachments":[],"bccRecipients":[],"toRecipients":["the.das@gmail.com","dasthe@gmail.com"],"body":"Take a look at <b>this<b/>:"}]]
```

Please Let me know where I am doing Wrong.

In config.xml  File `<plugin name="EmailComposer" value="EmailComposer" />` I add this in plugIn

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your plugin has been added correctly,but some error occur in plugin file. I think you may create another project in xcode and compile to check if bugs exist in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "" instead of [] like this

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer(
"Look at this photo", // subject
"Take a look at <b>this<b/>:", // body
"the.das@gmail.com,dasthe@gmail.com", // toRecipients
"", // toRecipients
"", // bccRecipients
true, // bIsHTML
);
```

in code, we expect string for separate then by @","

```
...
[picker setToRecipients:[ toRecipientsString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
...
```

I hope this helps